# How to adjust Related Page Thumb Sizes on single page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, single

If you view my test page: http://test.activestatedesigns.com/product/backpacking-colorado-flag/ you’ll see the related products layout isn’t great. Is there a way to reduce the size of these thumbs to better fit on my page? I’d like 4 related products that fit in one row across the site width. I cannot find this setting anywhere, can you please help? This is the same issue with my shop and category pages as well (I am using essential grid at top of page and want to turn off WooCommerce on second half because the display is terrible) http://test.activestatedesigns.com/shop/

Thanks in advance for your help!
Lorne

Answer (score 0):

It seems your using a commercial theme 'Jupiter', and it looks like your having trouble styling the related products section. You probably do best if you go ask the creator of the Jupiter theme how to achieve this.